# Converting integer to date in format MDD to 'M/DD' in Python

Tags: python

I have an array of dates from January to June in the format MDD, for example May 31st is 531. I want to know a quick easy way to change that to a string formatted '5/31'.

Sorry I have no code, I don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a formatted string:

```
d = '531'
print(f"{d[:-2]}/{d[-2:]}")
```

Output:

```
5/31
```

Comment: What about 2412?

Comment: @Ronald You mean 1224. Added it.

Comment: As for me more interesting 111 value (1/11 or 11/1)

Comment: @dimay Logically, it'll be 1/11 :)

Comment: Yes in this case but if we take all 12 months

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
l = 531
day = l % 100
month = int((l - day) / 100)
date = str(month) + r'/' + str(day)
print('date: ', date) #date:  5/31
```